# overloading using an argument that was returned from a method with generic return type

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I have a Java overloading issue that I cannot understand.

The code is as follows:

```
private void f(Object o) {
}

private void f(Collection c) {
}

private <T> T dummy() {
    return null;
}

private void g() {
    f(dummy());
}
```

Now, dummy() returns an object of an undefined type so erasure should lead to a type of Object. However, the invocation f(dummy()) actually calls f(Collection) and not f(Object). Why is this the case?

Comment: I think since `T` can be anything and the compiler always chooses the most *specific* method for overloading, the one with `Collection` is chosen. Because `Object > Collection`

Comment: It is a good question, but it was already discussed

Comment: thanks for your response. Could not quickly find the answer to it but now I know.